# Question on a jquery-ajax function, Using Django

Tags: django, jquery

I am new to Django, Ajax and HTML. I am currently developing a simple website for learning purposes.

The site fetches recent news from my db and displays the 5 latest news entry. This should be done without the user refreshing the whole page.

The code below may not seem much, but it is the the result of a painfully long learning process from my end.

**Question comes at the end.**

**url.py**

```
site_media = '/django/feed/site_media/'

urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^$', 'recent.views.recent_feed_view'),
# Site media
(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
{'document_root': site_media}),)
```

**models.py**

```
class news(models.Model):
   question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   pub_date = models.DateField('date published')
```

**views.py**

```
def recent_feed_view(request):
show_results = False
new_feed = []
if 'get_feed' in request.GET:
    show_results = True
    new_feed = news.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'new_feed': new_feed,
    'show_results': show_results,})

if request.GET.has_key('ajax'):
    return render_to_response('feed_list.html', variables)
else:
    return render_to_response('recent_news.html', variables)
```

**recent_news.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/jquery.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="/site_media/get_feed.js"></script>
</head>

 <body>
    <form id="search_feed_form" method="get">
        <input name = "get_feed" type="submit" value="get_feed" />
    </form>

  <div id="get_feed_div">
      {% if show_results %}
          {% include "feed_list.html" %}
      {% endif %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**feed_list.html**

```
    <ol class="news">
    {% for news in new_feed %}
        {{ news.question }}
        <br />
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

**get_feed.js**

```
function get_feed_js() {
$('#get_feed_div').load('/?ajax&get_feed');
return false;}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search_feed_form').submit(get_feed_js);});
```

**Questions:**

1- How can I modify my javascript function so that the page automatically fetches the latest news feed, say every 1 min, without having to press the button?

2- Is there a way to fetch the latest news feed when the user navigates to my website tab? (i.e.: he was currently viewing another tab on his browser and just clicked on the tab with my site on it)

I would greatly appreciate it if I could receive some tips / links to useful materiel that can help me move forward in this endeavor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval`: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

```
setInterval('get_feed_js()', 60000); // call func every 60 seconds





$(window).one('focus', function() { // without one, I infinitely get focus event
    get_feed_js(); // call function on tab focus
})
```

Comment: the setInterval was exactly what I needed thx a mil!!! I have a quick question about the $(window).one('focus', function(): it only works, and calls get_feed_js() the first time I load my webpage; When I navigate between different tabs on my browser, do some random activity and then return to my site's tab. new feeds do not get loaded. Is this normal behavior for the function?